# Regular Expression for International Phone Number

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter app that should validate a phone number. I want to use a regex expression for validation. all numbers should start with +260. The 4th digit can either be a 7 or 9 and the rest of the 8 digits should be any digits between 0-9. Can you help me achieve this? for example, the full number should be (+260(7 or 9)********). I tried using the below expression in my code its not working.

```
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Phone number cannot be empty';
                }
                if (!RegExp(r'^\+260[79][567]\d{7}$').hasMatch(value)) {
                  return 'Enter valid number';
                }
                return null;
              },
```

Comment: But you restricted the 5th digit to `5`, `6` or `7`. Do you mean you just want to replace `[567]\d{7}` with `\d{8}`?

Comment: I copied that code from somewhere. i am a beginner and I don't know much about regex.

Comment: So use `r'^\+260[79]\d{8}$'`

Comment: You can try this: `^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$` It might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
^\+(?:\d\s?){6,14}\d$
```

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \+                       '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (between 6 and
                           14 times (matching the most amount
                           possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                             (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){6,14}                  end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```